# How to check asynchronously Google speech API output stream transcriptions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to create a Ruby on Rails application that will use a microphone and web sockets to generate real-time speech to text transcription using Google Speech service.

I have successfully sent an audio stream through a web socket to the application, and I am also able to send and receive a transcript from the stream using the `streaming_recognize` method on an object created using `Google::Cloud::Speech.speech`. The problem is that I receive the transcript only after the stream has ended.

I tried to use `async` gem to send audio to `input_stream`and read `output_stream` in the `Async` blocks. The thing is the block which reads an `output_stream` blocks the entire application even the second block which sends audio chunks to the `input_stream`.

Here is my code (blocking):

```rb
require 'google/cloud/speech'
require 'gapic-common'
require 'async'

audio_file_path = './output.webm'
speech = Google::Cloud::Speech.speech

audio_content = File.binread audio_file_path
bytes_total   = audio_content.size
bytes_sent    = 0
chunk_size    = 32_000

input_stream = Gapic::StreamInput.new
output_stream = speech.streaming_recognize input_stream

config = {
  config: {
    encoding:                 :WEBM_OPUS,
    sample_rate_hertz:        48_000,
    language_code:            "pl-PL",
    enable_word_time_offsets: true
  }
}
input_stream.push streaming_config: config

Sync do |task|
  # Simulated streaming from a microphone
  task.async do
    # Stream bytes...
    while bytes_sent < bytes_total
      puts "Sending audio chunk"
      input_stream.push audio_content: audio_content[bytes_sent, chunk_size]
      puts "Sent audio chunk"
      bytes_sent += chunk_size
      sleep 1
    end

    puts "Stopped passing"
    input_stream.close
  end

  task.async do
    loop do
      puts "Checking output stream if any to read?"
      puts output_stream.any? # If you comment out this line everything runs smoothly again
      puts "Output stream checked"
      sleep 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Bidirectional streaming speech recognition is only available via the gRPC API. See v1 reference https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#google.cloud.speech.v1.Speech.StreamingRecognize

Comment: @GangChen Yeah, but on the other hand I should already have the gRPC client – according to https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-cloud-speech/latest/Google-Cloud-Speech#Google__Cloud__Speech_speech_class_

Comment: ok, did you process your audio stream into chunks (100ms preferred)? and when using streamingclient, the first request should send the streaming config, then the audio chunks in the subsequent requests. samples here https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/endless-streaming-tutorial

Comment: I divided my audio file into 32 kB chunks, I'm not sure what is the equivalent time span in the webm encoding. Also as you have advised I have sent the streaming config as the first request. My attempt was based on the Google examples from documentation, however in the ruby language I couldn't find any example in which I'd be able to read transcription and simultanously send audio stream.